# Copy Portion of data from one Col to another in same table

Tags: sql

I have a column in a table that has data like this. 123.45.678. I want to do a SQL update that will copy just the data in positions 5 & 6 only, the 45, and put it in a different column on the same row of data.

I have dorking around with this

```
UPDATE Termination 
  SET Division = Left(CoDivCC, InStr(3, CoDivCC, ".") +2)
WHERE [Term Ind] = "TERM";
```

The above gives me the following result: 123.45

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Copying data around will eventually lead to data inconsistency. Create a view instead, or have a computed/virtual column.

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the same position, you can use `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('123.45.678',5,2)
```